# Oracle SQL Developer script output not displaying readable format

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have queries that provide the output, but the output is really weird looking.  It doesn't scroll over to look at the output, and the columns are really wide for things that are less than 20 characters.  How do I get it to look normal? This is using Oracle SQL Developer. I searched online, but this doesn't seem to be what I need to do: [format output archive](https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2015/05/how-to-format-your-script-output-in-sql-developer-by-default/). Although, I don't see how to get to the preference screen they are referring to either.

This is a portion of the output:

```
      RAK      SHEL SLT
---------- ---------- ------------------------------ PRT                                     BRDBND_
---------------------------------------- ---------- DSLAM
-------------------------------------------------- VEND
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------- MODE
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------- PORT_ADDR  CARRIER_ID
----------------- ----------------------------------------------------- CIRC_DE SERVICE SHELF_PT_NUM         CARD_PART_NUM
---------- ---------- ------------------------- ------------------------- CARD_PT_DESC             
-----------------------------------
    3317 270812 1179G1                 1170F1
```

As you can see, hopefully, it has really wide columns for the output, and column headers aren't at the top of the output window, it's in the output window. None of the output is more than 20 characters wide. I'm not sure why it's displaying that way.

Update: Plus, it's printing the column headers in the output window over and over again.

Comment: Show us your sql

Comment: The problem wasn't the sql.  It was the settings in developer.  @ZynonPutneyII answered it already.

Comment: glad it's answered, but you made us guess. Next time show us you entire script + settings, then we can give you an educated answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding this line at the beginning of your script. It appears that your SQL Developer settings are what is making this output unreadable.

NOTE: I am using SQL Developer version 18.1.0.095

Edit: Added command to suppress reprinting of headers (pagesize) to 80 lines.

```
set sqlformat ansiconsole;
set pagesize 80;
```

Comment: It still seems to be printing the header every 10 output lines.  It's a little better though.

Comment: set pagesize 80 will make the output 80 lines before it reprints header.